# rdp display problems after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-10

I've just upgraded a desktop machine to windows 10, from windows 7.  This machine had rdp connections to several server machines (win2008 r2) all of which worked fine pre-upgrade.

On each new connection now the display seems corrupted, changing any of the experience settings on the rdp connection doesn't improve anything at all.

Here is a sample screenshot:
[image]

Does anybody have any information on how something like this could be fixed?

Comment: Reinstall lateat video card driver in your desktop.

Comment: I tried that but it made no visible difference :(

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, I found that although my RDP connections worked, it used an older version of RDP seemingly.

To resolve the issues, I had to download a new RDP program from the Windows Store called Microsoft Remote Desktop Preview.  Once I connected with that new program, it worked fine, no visual issues, though I couldn't import my previous rdp profiles.